# Spring roo not recognizing date format before saving json

Tags: mysql, spring, date, jpa, spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo on top of MySQL. I pull dates out via the Roo-generated JSON methods, make changes to that data in a browser form, and save it back via the Roo-generated JSON methods.

The date format I'm getting out is `yyyy-MM-dd`, standard MySQL date format. I'm using a calendaring widget on the browser to ensure the date I'm submitting is the same format.

Unfortunately my data doesn't go right through the `...FromJson()` method, failing with the error:

```
Parsing date 2007-12-12 was not recognized as a date format
```

I presume that the problem is that it's coming out as a string, but JPA feels like it needs to generate a `Date` object to update.

I'll happily show my code about this, but it's nothing Roo didn't build for me.

It occurs to me that there's something it's referring to when it says "recognized as a date format". Is there somewhere I can change what date formats it knows?

EDIT: With @nowaq's help, here's the ultimate answer:

```
public static Lease fromJsonToLease(String json) {
    return new JSONDeserializer<Lease>()
            .use(null, Lease.class)
            .use(Date.class, new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            .deserialize(json);
}
```

That way JSONDeserializer knows what class it's dealing with AND builds a formatter for all the dates in that class. Wicked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very related to this one: [Spring-roo REST JSON controllers mangle date fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311962/spring-roo-rest-json-controllers-mangle-date-fields) Take a look and make sure you're using correct DateTrasformer(s) with your JSON deserializers. E.g.

```
new JSONDeserializer()
      .use(Date.class, new DateTransformer("yyyy-MM-dd") )
      .deserialize( people );
```

Comment: Turns out I needed two `.use` calls, one to define the class I'm working with, and one to configure the datetransformer for the dates in that class. Thanks!

Comment: @DanRay I am doing your solution by adding new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd") but it looks like the DateFormater is not working? I need to cast it to ObjectFactory but it cannot be casted to this type.